# JSF 2.0 & Facelets

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, facelets

I wish to have a Master-Page, and switch content in this. I currently have it working by having the content pane of my masterpage defined by `<ui:include src="#{navigation.currentPane}" />`

The navigation bean holds the current navigation path for the content facelet. The content is updated with ajax.

Is this the correct way? Does it have any downsides?

Comment: This is not SEO friendly. You should do it the other way round so that every page has its own bookmarkable URL.

Comment: Does this also apply if its content that should only be accesible while autenticated and logged in ?

Comment: Yes, just restrict access to those URLs by either container managed authentication or a homegrown filter (or a 3rd party authentication framework like Spring Security)

Comment: So if i want that master-page apperance, what i should do is example have home.xhtml & forum.xhtml and then use a template header for an example to keep that consistent?

Comment: Something like as 2nd example of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792862/how-to-include-another-xhtml-in-xhtml-using-jsf-2-0-facelets/4793959#4793959

Comment: Thanks man! +1 to you kind sir !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be problems if you use ViewScoped beans. EL in src can lead recreating your bean with every request. With SessionScoped beans I think it works fine.

Comment: Abusing session scoped beans for view scoped data is a bad idea.

Comment: it would be / is sessionscoped. But my concern, is really if this is a hack, rather than "the way" :)